# Is Core Bluetooth framework intrinsically asynchronous?

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-bluetooth

When I utilize the CB framework in my app, I don't introduce any concurrency nor reactive approach and everything works fine. UI is not blocked when I receive over 100 samples per second from peripheral.

Does that mean it is designed to work asynchronously?

I haven't found any resources that states it's asynchronous nature, nor have I found any implementation where someone introduces dispatch async or background threads while working with Core Bluetooth.

Is it safe to say that Core Bluetooth framework is intrinsically asynchronous and one should not bother with `dispatch_async` and thing like that while working with Bluetooth on iOS?

**EDIT:**

this is how I initialize it

```
centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
peripheralManager = CBPeripheralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil
```

So they apparently run in the main queue. How come it does not block the UI at all?

Comment: "By specifying the dispatch queue as nil, the central manager dispatches central role events using the main queue."

Comment: I am not sure what "central role events" means though

Comment: Just because things happen on the main queue doesn't mean the UI will be blocked. The UI will only freeze if the main queue is blocked; if a blocking `wait` is used. The Bluetooth hardware receives events and delivers them to iOS.  iOS then has to dispatch those events and it does so in the queue you specify but that queue is not blocked, waiting for those events. The short answer to your question is "yes".  Almost everything in modern operating systems, particularly user-interactive systems like iOS is event driven. Polling is inefficient in terms of CPU and battery.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for your comment, If you could elaborate on one more thing: Is there any reason to bother with perfoming BLE operations in different queue than main then? Feel free to post it as the answer to my question along with the things you wrote above. Thanks!